# Why isn't there an article before "proportion"?

Tags: articles, zero-article, wh-questions

Why isn't there an article before " proportion" in the following sentence?

> What proportion of people who are HIV-positive go on to develop AIDS?

Comment: Because 'what' is before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What* is functioning as a determiner, so you cannot use an article as well.

> *What town do you come from?*

> *What song did they play?*

(You may occasionally encounter *what a* or *what the*, but only in exclamations, not in questions: *What a man!*)